# How to fix this warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "public"?

Tags: php, drupal, filestream, drupal-7

I need to read some meta information from the downloaded file. But I do not know how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
// Path form field_file
$file = 'public://directory/filename.txt';
file_get_contents($file);
```

This code causes this warning:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "public" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Any idea of what I am doing wrong, please?

Comment: What is the "public" wrapper? Never heard of it. Is this something Drupal specific? What kind of Meta information do you need to read from what downloaded file?

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/555118 Yes, it is drupal speciffic wrapper. I need get name and type of the font from TTF file.

Answer (score 4):

There are three internal stream wrappers *private*, *public* and *temporary*, they are defined in [this](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--stream_wrappers.inc/7) file.

You may want [file_get_mimetype()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_get_mimetype/7), file_get_contents is a PHP function and won't be aware of the drupal file api.

```
file_get_contents(drupal_realpath($file));
```

Would do the trick for reading.

For an upload take a look at [file_save_upload()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_save_upload/7)

Comment: Thanks. But it works strange. If "directory" is not exist drupal_realpath will return FALSE.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that these wrappers aren't available in `hook_boot()` or some other early stages.
So please move your code into another place and check if this would fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The fix I'm using is the following code:

```
echo base_path().variable_get('file_public_path',conf_path().'/files');
```

It still doesn't explain why streams aren't working.